# Python add line under another line based on specific pattern

Tags: python, node.js

I created a little Python program to send SMS to my phone so I can access HTML webpages without spending too much money. It parses the code and splits it into blocks of 160 characters on multiple text files (ex.: split_file_aa), which names are stored in a list, and with a "while" loop it stores the contents of, say, 'split_file_aa' and 'split_file_ab' in a variable called 'smstext', one at a time.

So here's my problem : I have a program in NodeJS that contains constants (ex.: `const message = "__init__"`), like in this example :

```
// Some JS content above
const message = 'init'
```

What I would want to do would be to add the contents of 'smstext' in the file each time the 'while' loop is executed, in the form of `const message2 = '<html code here>'` or `const message3 = '<html code here>'` and so on, and so on, so my code after that would likely be

```
// Some JS content above
const message = 'init'
const message2 = '<html code here>'
const message3 = '<another bunch of html here>'
```

and so on.

If you have questions (because I'm not sure if I really explained my problem), feel free to ask !

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how the system works. Your python code runs where?

Comment: Python code runs on the server machine (computer) and I'm trying to insert the contents of a variable (smstext) into the nodeJS file shown in the question. The 'smstext' gets replaced every time the 'while' loop is executed, and so I want it to be imprinted in the 'const message' thing every time, as message2, message3, message4, etc. to create a coherent SMS chain which will be sent.

Comment: You have a js function that returns the sms content? How do you know it's over and there are no more messages?

Comment: I count the number of 'split_file_**' in Python, I have a variable for that, call it 'listingslength'

Comment: Ok, use a for loop to read and concatenate the pieces together.